# Can someone explain why I have build task error MSB3491?

Tags: msbuild-task

When building using Visual Studio 2022, targeting net7.0, net6.0, and netstandard2.0, the build fails with the following warnings in the build output (I don't think multi-targeting has any impact):

```bash
>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3588,5): warning MSB3491: Could not write lines to file "obj\Debug\net6.0\.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs". Access to the path 'D:\src\XXX\obj\Debug\net6.0\.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs' is denied.
>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3588,5): warning MSB3491: Could not write lines to file "obj\Debug\net7.0\.NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs". Access to the path 'D:\src\XXX\obj\Debug\net7.0\.NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs' is denied.
>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3588,5): warning MSB3491: Could not write lines to file "obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\.NETStandard,Version=v2.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs". Access to the path 'D:\src\XXXn\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\.NETStandard,Version=v2.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs' is denied.
```

When logs are set to verbose, the following is emitted (only including for net7.0 TFM):

```bash
>    Target GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
>      Building target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" completely.
>      Input file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.targets" is newer than output file "obj\Debug\net7.0\.NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs".
>      Task "WriteLinesToFile"
>        C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3588,5): warning MSB3491: Could not write lines to file "obj\Debug\net7.0\.NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs". Access to the path 'D:\src\XXX\obj\Debug\net7.0\.NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs' is denied.
>        The previous error was converted to a warning because the task was called with ContinueOnError=true.
>        Build continuing because "ContinueOnError" on the task "WriteLinesToFile" is set to "true".
>      Done executing task "WriteLinesToFile" -- FAILED.
>    Done building target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" in project "HatTrick.DbEx.CodeTemplating.csproj".
```

The warnings reference temporary files created by the build process prior to compilation.

Things I've tried to figure this out:

- If I run `dotnet build` from the command line, it results in the same.
- If I change branches/pull or clean/build/rebuild, the build fails - there are no error messages in the output, only the warnings above.
- If I restart Visual Studio and rebuild, the build succeeds, but still has the warnings.
- I've tried on another machine and it works as expected (no errors or warnings) - I cannot reproduce this issue on another machine.

I don't think it's a file/directory permission exception because I can rebuild and the build process outputs the assemblies to the `bin` and `obj` folders just fine.